# Javascript - Calling a Function that is an Argument of another Function?

Tags: javascript

If a functionA is an argument for another functionB, and functionB has a loop in which it calls functionA, how do we repeatedly call functionA instead of storing functionA as a constant var?

```
function rollDie() {
    var die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    return die[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function rollFalseDie() {
    var falseDie = [1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4];
    return falseDie[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function rollDiceNTimes (function1, function2, n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        if (function1 > function2) return 1 + rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
        else return rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have two functions that represent rolls of a real and fake die, and a function that will roll both dice N times and return the number of times the value of the first function is greater than the value of the second function. However, when I run rollDiceNTimes(rollDie(), rollFalseDie(), 50), the output is either 0 or 50, which seems to suggest that the first values rollDie() and rollFalseDie() are being stored and compared 50 times.

How do I modify the body of my functions so that rollDie() and rollFalseDie() are called repeatedly, while still taking in two functions and a number N as arguments for rollDiceNTimes()?

Comment: `return falseDie = [Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]`  ... hmmm

Comment: Instead of `rollDiceNTimes(rollDie(), rollFalseDie(), 50),`, call `rollDiceNTimes(rollDie, rollFalseDie, 50),`. Don't call functions you're passing as arguments. Just pass them.

Comment: Right, and also: in the body of rollDiceNTimes, OP should *call* the functions and compare results, not try to compare only functions arguments

Comment: I disagree with the closing reason. This is not just missing a `;` at the end of a Java line and asking why the code doesn't compile. This seems like a misunderstanding of how you can pass along functions and use them as argument in another. The fact that two pairs of parenthesis need to be added (and two other pairs removed in the first call !), does not make it a "simple typgraphical error." IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

## What you might want

Do the following 2  changes :

1) Actually pass *functions* to your first call (**remove parenthesis for functions passed as argument**)

```
rollDiceNTimes(rollDie, rollFalseDie, 50)
```

2) Change your rollDiceNTimes to actually execute the functions parameters (by **adding parenthesis next to the function name**)

```
function rollDiceNTimes (function1, function2, n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        if (function1() > function2()) return 1 + rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
        else return rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which means the same as this, if you want some more separated steps :

```
function rollDiceNTimes (function1, function2, n) {
    var value1 = function1();
    var value2 = function2();
    if (n > 0) {
        if (value1 > value2) return 1 + rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
        else return rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Your error explanation

To be clear :

```
function myFunction() { 
    return 42; 
}
```

`myFunction` --> the actual function named "myFunction". Think of it as "an executable object"

`myFunction()` --> 42 (the result of the call to myFunction). Could be a number for instance (though there are functions that return other functions, but this is not the case here)

When you write `function1 > function2` , you are trying to compare function objects (not the *number results* of each function !) which make little sense here.

But you are saying that you call your main recursive function this way :

```
rollDiceNTimes(rollDie(), rollFalseDie(), 50)
```

so it means that the actual arguments are **not** functions. They are results of the functions. With the names, you think you pass functions, but you are not actually doing that. You pass fixed values, the 2 same over and over again in all your recursion chain !

for instance, if the first call to `rollDie()` return 3, and the first `rollFalseDie()` returns 4,

```
rollDiceNTimes(rollDie(), rollFalseDie(), 50)
```

would be the same call as :

```
rollDiceNTimes(3, 4, 50)
```

And in this case, it will run the "else" part, so `return rollDiceNTimes(function1, function2, n-1);` which is the same as `return rollDiceNTimes(3, 4, 49);` (becasue your vairable named "function1" and "function2" are just fixed numbers, not functions.

and so on until rollDiceNTimes(3, 4, 0), which will return zero.

Same logic will iterate 50 times with 1 + 1 + 1 ... (50 times) and yields 50 if the first two arguments are in the other order .

you could also just write `if (function1() > function2())` as well, but I just wanted to separate the call and the comparison to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have a recursive function call itself be the last statement of the function. Currently tail call optimization is removed but may be added again in the future. Recursive calls will be implemented as loop by the compiler when tco comes back.

So rollDiceNTimes has a function called recur that will call itself incrementing a counter if 1 is greater than 2 and decrementing `n` (times rolled). If n is zero it'll return the counter instead.

I removed repeated code of `rollDie` and just created a function called `dice` this takes an array of values used for the faces of the dice and return a function that when called will return one of those faces (roll the dice).

```js
function dice(faces) {
  return function(){//return function 
    return faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
  }
}

function rollDiceNTimes (roll1,roll2, n) {
  function recur(total,n){
    if(n===0){
      return total;
    }
    return recur(
      total+(
        //ternary operator (like an if statement but shorter)
        (roll1()>roll2())
          ? 1
          : 0),
      n-1
    );
  }
  return recur(0,n);
}

console.log(
  rollDiceNTimes(
    dice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
    dice([1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
    50
  )
);
```

You can also pass the function what you want to do after a roll to `rollDiceNTimes` and get not only the amount of times 1 was bigger than 2 but the average of both rolled dices:

```js
function dice(faces) {
  return function(){//return function 
    return faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
  }
}

function rollDiceNTimes (afterRollFn, roll1,roll2, n) {
  function recur(total,n){
    if(n===0){
      return total;
    }
    return recur(
      afterRollFn(roll1(),roll2()),
      n-1
    );
  }
  return recur(0,n);
}

console.log(
  "One larger than two",
  rollDiceNTimes(
    (function (total) {//IIFE with total in closure
      return function (one,two) {
        //ternary operator (like an if statement but shorter)
        if (one>two) {
          total = total + 1;
        }
        return total;
      }
    }(0)),
    dice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
    dice([1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
    50
  )
);

console.log(
  "Average of one and two",
  rollDiceNTimes(
    (function (timesRolled,totalOne,totalTwo){//IIFE with totals in closure
      return function (one,two) {
        timesRolled = timesRolled+1;
        totalOne=totalOne+one;
        totalTwo=totalTwo+two;
        //average of both
        return [totalOne/timesRolled,totalTwo/timesRolled]
      };
    }(0,0,0)),
    dice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
    dice([1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
    50
  )
);
```